# Which spells does a spellslinger begin with in their spellbook, and which can they cast?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, character-creation, wizard, archetype

From the Wizard, **Spells**:

> **Starting Spells** (See Spellbooks below): A wizard begins play with a spellbook containing all 0-level wizard spells (except those from his opposed schools, if any; see Arcane Schools) plus three 1st-level spells of his choice. The wizard also selects a number of additional 1st-level spells equal to his Intelligence modifier to add to the spellbook. At each new wizard level, he gains two new spells of any spell level or levels that he can cast (based on his new wizard level) for his spellbook. At any time, a wizard can also add spells found in other wizards’ spellbooks to his own (see Magic).

From the Spellslinger, **Mage Bullets (Su)**:

> …
>   This ability replaces cantrips, but the spellslinger gains the *detect magic* and *read magic* cantrips and places them in his spellbook. He can cast either of these as 1st-level spells.

It seems as though by the RAW the spellslinger begins with all 0-level sorcerer/wizard spells but cannot cast them — except for *detect magic* and *read magic*, which can be cast as 1st-level spells.

Is this right? Is there some errata somewhere that addresses it?

Comment: That last bit is really weird, because nothing prevents a wizard from preparing and cast any of their cantrips as first level spells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems as though by the RAW **the spellslinger begins with all 0-level sorcerer/wizard spells** but cannot cast them — except for detect magic and read magic, which can be cast as 1st-level spells. Is this right?

Yes, that is (partially) right. [Cantrips](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Wizard/#TOC-Cantrips) reads:

> Wizards can prepare a number of cantrips, or 0-level spells, each day, as noted on Table: Wizard under “Spells per Day.” These spells are cast like any other spell, but they are not expended when cast and may be used again. A wizard can prepare a cantrip from an opposition school, but it uses up two of his available slots (see below).

So if cantrip is replaced, you lose all benefits listed on the ability's text, including the ability to cast cantrips at all. The spellslinger has no level 0 spell slots, and has to cast *Detect Magic* and *Read Magic* using first level slots.

However, I believe the intent was for them to begin with no cantrips at all, but the ability's text was not worded properly. That is evidenced when they gain two cantrips that they would already have from his other class feature (as you noted correctly). Due to this poor wording, you gain all cantrips on your spellbook, but cannot cast them unless you use spell slots of 1st level or higher.

Comment: To add to this, it is highly recommended that GMs strictly following RAW allow Spellslingers to not write the cantrips down  if they don't want to in order to leave the ~20 or so pages in their spellbook normally taken up by cantrips unfilled. Otherwise, unless the Spellslinger is into creating magic items using those spells, that just cut down on the number of spells the character can carry around with them.